# Missing Link for Scala and simplifying JDBC

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get hold of an article that is supposed to be at http://scala.sygneca.com/code/simplifying-jdbc, but for the last week that site has timed out and I can't find the link cached on Google either.  Does anyone know where I could find a copy of that article?

Thanks,
Ant

Comment: This was closed.  Where am I expected to ask such questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://web.archive.org/web/20101110111820/http://scala.sygneca.com/code/simplifying-jdbc

Answer (score 2):

The old wiki got not delete it got migrated, here is the page you look for on the new wiki:
https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Simplifying-jdbc

HTH